# Where is the httpd-vhosts.conf located in XAMPP?

Tags: xampp, virtualhost

Where can I find the httpd-vhosts.conf file to setup virtual hosts when using XAMPP?

Answer (score 1):

- Windows: `C:\XAMPP\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`
- Mac: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
- Linux: `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Note that you have to edit the `httpd.conf` in the parent folder to include the file:

```
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Alternatively, you can also insert virtual hosts in the `httpd-xampp.conf` which is included in XAMPP by default:

- Windows: `C:\XAMPP\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf`
- Mac: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`
- Linux: `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`